# Delete "unioned" non-contiguous range

Tags: excel, vba

**I can't use `rng.EntireRow.Delete` when the range is non-contiguous, and the range is built by Union.**

1. I know that I can delete multiple rows based on criteria by using sort and autofilter. I want to learn something new. I am not interested in backwards deleting or using loops, it's too time consuming.
2. **The code fails when the range "usun" is non-contiguous.**
3. While debugging: range "usun.Address" seems to be building correctly e.g. "$E$10:$E15,$E$20,$E$30:$E$32"

```vb
Sub delSomeRows()

    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").ListObjects(1)
       ' formulas into values
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Value = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value 

    ' Get the column reference to analysis
       Dim komorka      ' cell to be analysed
       Dim usun As Range    ' multiple ranges to delete
       Dim filter As Range  ' column in the table
       Set filter = tbl.ListColumns("Filtr").DataBodyRange

    ' Get Union range to delete
       For Each komorka In filter
           If Len(komorka.Value) <> 0 Then
                If usun Is Nothing Then
                    Set usun = komorka
                Else
                    Set usun = Application.Union(usun, komorka)
                End If
           End If
        Next komorka

    ' delete all rows at once
        usun.EntireRow.Delete ' ERROR 1004 HERE

End Sub
```

I am trying to delete some rows e.g. second, third and sixth or others at once using EntireRow.Delete on "Unioned" range.

Comment: You should be checking that the range is _something_ before you try deleting it. `If not usun Is Nothing Then usun.EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs that would be error 91 though.

Comment: If that was my solution to his problem I would have listed as an answer. Just throwing out an unrelated observation :-). I could have been more clear that I wasn't trying to solve his particular issue though.

Comment: Of course I've added watch usun.Address before to see if the range is nothing. But I added your lines to debug too. Stil the same. When using F8 key to run code one-by-one line the condition (Not nothing) is met, there is error 1004 as before.

Comment: Just for fun, can you try this: `Range("$E$10:$E15,$E$20,$E$30:$E$32").EntireRow.Delete`, which would be the same as `Range(usun.Address).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: OK got a repro - hold Ctrl key down and select the rows you want to delete in the table, by selecting the entire sheet rows (i.e. clicking the row headings) - notice the Delete command is disabled in the context menu; that's why you're getting error 1004 when you do it programmatically. Now do the same but instead of selecting row headings, select table rows; now you can delete the table rows, but not the sheet rows - `.EntireRow` is part of the problem.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs not working even with fully qualified name ThisWorkbook.Sheets("..."). After converting table to range the code works. Very strange

Comment: @MathieuGuindon but on the ribbon in your case there is option "delete rows sheet" (i have not english office version) :) and it works by manually clicking it

Comment: That would be "Delete table rows" - and it works because it's working off the ListObject, not the worksheet

Comment: @MathieuGuindon No, I am clicking outside table and using delete rows on Home tab on Ribbon, not just table rows delete. Office 2016 here.

Comment: huh, interesting.

Comment: you can try `usun.EntireRow.select` and then manually deleting the selected range to see what error shows up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to delete table rows like this:

[image: non-contiguous entire sheet rows selected]

Excel won't let you delete non-contiguous entire sheet rows when a table /listobject is involved - either programmatically or through the UI (well, at least from the context menu - works from the Home Ribbon tab for some reason).

What you want to do is this:

[image: listrows are selected; non-contiguous deletion works]

You can't delete sheet rows, but now Excel understands what we're trying to achieve. The trick is to get this selection programmatically.

Iterate the `ListObject`'s `ListRows` instead, and `Union` the `ListRow.Range`; the unioned resulting range's `Delete` method will then work (don't use `.EntireRow`).

This worked for my dummy table, from the immediate pane:

```
union(sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListRows(2).Range,sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListRows(4).Range).Delete
```

So with your code, I'd iterate `tbl.ListRows` and `Union` the `ListRow.Range` items - not tested, but this should work:

```
Dim filterColumn As Long
filterColumn = tbl.ListColumns("Filtr").Index

Dim currentRow As ListRow
For Each currentRow In tbl.ListRows
    If Len(currentRow.Range.Cells(ColumnIndex:=filterColumn).Value) <> 0 Then
        If usun Is Nothing Then
            Set usun = currentRow.Range
        Else
            Set usun = Application.Union(usun, currentRow.Range)
        End If            
    End If
Next

If Not usun Is Nothing Then usun.Delete
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working. I must to analyse my and your code tommorrow, today I am exhausted yet :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to manually select a cell in various non-contiguous rows and then have macro delete Columns A-H of the rows containing selected cells (but not entire row).  I couldn't find any help for this that I could make work but made it happen with this code:

```
Sub Deletion() 'Deletes col A-H from each row containing a selected cell, moves up cells below
Dim RinQ As Range
Dim EachOne(100) As Integer 'one-dimensional array (100 is just a number I know is plenty)
Dim b, e As Byte 'assumes I'll not select > 256 cells
Dim RR As Range
Set RinQ = Selection  'this will be all the selected cells
For Each RR In RinQ 'For each selected cell
    e = e + 1 'identifying number for selected cell
    EachOne(e) = RR.Row 'this will be number of each row containing a selected cell
Next RR
For b = e To 1 Step -1 'from bottom up because row number <> that in EachOne after delete
    Range("A" & EachOne(b) & ":H" & EachOne(b)).Delete (xlShiftUp) 'the deletion
Next b
End Sub
```