# Delete Excel Table row using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete the lines of a `TEAMS` Table when the `Value2` of column `D` does not match a variable `department` (String). I'm able to detect the rows I want to delete, but the delete method causes a "`delete method of range class failed`" error.

Here is a simplified code snippet.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To wkbook.Worksheets("T").Range("TEAMS").Rows.Count
  With wkbook.Worksheets("T").Range("TEAMS[D]")(i)
    If .Value2 <> department Then
      .EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  End With
Next i
```

Comment: Possiblyy a standard row delete issue where you should loop from the bottom to the top. Try: For i = wkbook.Worksheets("T").Range("TEAMS").Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a `ListObject`/table - use the `ListObject` API.

```
Dim table As ListObject
Set table = wkbook.Worksheets.ListObjects("TEAMS")

Dim colIndex As Long
Set colIndex = table.ListColumns("D").Index

Dim toDelete As Range

Dim currentRow As ListRow
For Each currentRow In table.ListRows
    If currentRow.Range.Cells(ColumnIndex:=colIndex).Value <> department Then
        If toDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set toDelete = currentRow.Range
        Else
            Set toDelete = Application.Union(toDelete, currentRow.Range)
    End If
Next

If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then toDelete.Delete
```

Pretty similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57530306/1188513).

Comment: I'm assuming that it should be `Table.ListRows`, no?