# excel vba delete method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a code that deletes select rows from a table where the column "OG Row" <> "x". I am able to delete the rows manually, but when I run the code i get this error "Delete method of range class failed"

```
For Each Row In tblAlloc.ListRows
        If Row.Range(1, tblAlloc.ListColumns("OG Row").Index).Value <> "x" Then

            If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDelete = Row.Range(1, 1).EntireRow
            Else
                Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, Row.Range(1, 1).EntireRow)
            End If

        End If
Next Row

rngToDelete.Delete
```

Comment: Why don't you delete the rows as they are identified? What's the benefit of collecting them in a non-contiguous range first?

Comment: @teylyn I tried doing both ways and it didn’t work either way

Comment: To delete each row as it is identified, process the range from the bottom, not the top. And "didn't work" is really hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: They both give the same error “delete method of range class failed”. The sheet is not protected and I can’t delete the rows manually

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529933/delete-unioned-non-contiguous-range